Why do diodes have different models?
When soldering some stuff, I accidentally reversed the direction of the diode, and now I can't get it out. I was thinking of cutting its leads, but the leads would be too short to solder back on. So, I thought of replacing it, but I don't have the exact same model. Wikipedia said that diodes are semiconductors, which, according to Wikipedia, is a metal. So why do chunks of metal have different models? I get that they might have multiple voltage/current ratings, but why? Isn't it just a chunk of metal?

Semiconductors are not necessarily metal. Moreover, in order to be useful they are not pure material, but "doped" with some impurities to give it the properties we need.

Semiconductors are very definitely not metals.

"Chunk of metal" is a gross over-simplification. But basically different diodes have different characteristics. The metal analogy is not so bad actually... Would you build an airplane out of lead or a bridge out of silver? No, you'd pick the most appropriate metal with suitable characteristics for the specific task.

If it were a metal, it wouldn't be a semiconductor -- actually, no combination of regular [pure] metals can have a diode characteristic; something fundamentally special is going on here. You might then suppose, this effect is special enough that it can have many variations, subtle or otherwise, that might be deserving of different labels?

Not sure what bit of wikipedia you were reading. A semiconductor is a semi-metal, or a conductor with conductivity somewhere between a metal and an insulator. And to make it do something interesting, it is not 'merely' a chunk. By your logic, a V8 auto engine is, for instance, merely a chunk of several metals.

Tell that to wikipedia

@Neil_UK Technically, there's a subtle distinction between semiconductors and semimetals; semimetals have no bandgap, but their conduction and valence bands don't overlap due to different peak locations in momentum space. They're basically the zero- or negative-bandgap limiting case of an indirect-bandgap semiconductor. See this diagram.

A diode is more like a screwdriver than a chunk of metal. In screwdrivers, the metal part does the job, but it obviously has a shape, the alloy used and the heat treatment affect its properties, and there is a handle as well. Diodes are not all equal for the same reason screwdrivers are not all equal: the detailed specifications matter for the application.
Similarly, saying “I need a diode” is like saying “I need a screwdriver”. If you asked me personally, with no other details, you’d get a basic 7” long #2 Philips head screwdriver, or a 1N4001 diode. Those are good for some common applications, but still there’s a wide variety of other screwdrivers… and diodes.
There are many construction details to a diode, similarly as they’d be in a screwdriver. They determine how exactly a diode performs. If you’ve used screwdrivers a lot, you’ll appreciate that the details of their construction matter if you’re not just a very casual user. Same with diodes: a lot of simple hobby projects can work with a 1N4001. Once you go past the simplest of project, you’ll need different diodes - and different screwdrivers.
